# Is the BOM an OS(Win, Nix . . . ) or encoding standard (UTF-8, ASCII . . .) concept?

Tags: text, encoding, byte-order-mark

Is the BOM a Windows characterisitc or a characteristic of some encoding method?

I write code in Windows 7 and Linux.  I have the option of choosing how I want my code encoded.  I want to be able to switch between both OS's with out a headache.  I'm somewhat sure I have acesss to all the characters I need using ASCII.  What other issues do I need to consider when transferring between OS's.  What text encodings are not standard dependent (ASCII vs Unicode vs UT-8) but OS dependent (Linux vs. Windows).

Comment: it's an _obsolete_ encoding standard.  it only has meaning for UTF-16 and similar.  don't use it.

Comment: But it might be present in UTF-8 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BOM is a Unicode encoding thing, nothing to do with Windows and/or UNIX specifically.

Probably the most ubiquitous encoding is UTF-8 and this is happily totally compatible with ASCII if you only use the ASCII character set.

Comment: Thanks. Do you recomend an encoding standard for writing code?  I would guess ASCII b.c. it is simple.

Comment: @Chris, I tend to use UTF-8 for pretty much _everything,_ so I guess that would be my recommendation :-)

Comment: Note - UTF-8 is variable width 1-4 bytes. So if you only use the ASCII character set (128 characters) it will only use one byte like ASCII.